# Regex for number at the end of string?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, numbers

I want to find out if a string ends with number (with/without decimal). If it ends, I want to extracts it.

```
"Test1" => 1
"Test"  => NOT FOUND
"Test123" => 123
"Test1.1" => 1.1
```

I have missed a few details.
1. Prior to number, string can contain special characters also
2. It is single line, not multiline.

Comment: `@"(-?[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)$"`

Comment: what do you expect in the string preceding the final number - just letters or basically anything ?

Comment: letters, special characters

Comment: When you say "string" did you mean multiline or single line?

Answer (score 10):

give this pattern a try,

```js
\d+(\.\d+)?$
```

A version  with a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-in-regular-expressions):

```js
\d+(?:\.\d+)?$
```

Answer (score 3):

Matches line start, any chars after that and a a number (with optional decimal part) at the end of the string (allowing trailing whitespace characters). The fist part is a lazy match, i.e. it will match the lowest number of chars possible leaving the whole number to the last part of the expression.

```
^.*?(\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?)\s*$
```

My test cases

```
"Test1
"Test
"Test123
"Test1.1
test 1.2 times 1 is 1.2
test 1.2 times 1 is ?
test 1.2 times 1 is 134.2234
1.2
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the following regex in c# `(\d+)$`

Answer (score 2):

A regex for a string that ends with a number: `@"\d$"`. Use http://regexpal.com/ to try out regexes.

Of course, that just tells you that the last character is a number. It doesn't capture anything other than the last character. To capture the number only this is needed: `@"\d*\.?\d+$"`.

If your string can be more complicated, eg "Test1.2 Test2", and you want both numbers: `@"\d*\.?\d+\b"`.

Comment: @JoannaTurban the regex works for the last example too. It just checks whether the last character in the string is a number.

Comment: @Esailija ah I misunderstood, I thought he wanted to know if the string ended with a number. In that case he could just grab the whole string, was my reasoning!

Comment: if you make the dot and the digits after the dot separate optional groups you can end up with a match "1."

Comment: @JoannaTurban fair point, I wonder if .2 should be a valid number

Answer (score 1):

use this regex `[a-zA-Z]+\d+([,.]\d+)?\b$`
if you want digit only use this one `(?<=[a-zA-Z]+)\d+([,.]\d+)?\b$`